# Negative exponent in the denominator with chain rule applied to square root.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, exponentiation, chain-rule

Differentiate $f(x) = x \tan^{-1}\sqrt{x}$

Solution:
$$f'(x) = x \frac{1}{{1+(\sqrt{x}})^2} \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2} + \tan^{-1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2(1+x)} + \tan^{-1}\sqrt{x}$$

I see the chain rule is being applied to $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator, resulting in $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$ however, the solution has $\sqrt{x}$ in the numerator.

My question: Why does the $\sqrt{x}$ move to the numerator?
The differentiation takes place on a function in the denominator which results in a negative exponent.  I understand negative exponents in the denominator move to the numerator.

My (edited) question: Why does $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$ not equal $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$?

Update: answered.

Comment: Did you notice that you are multiplying $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$ by $\frac{\color{blue}{x}}{1 + x}$?

Comment: There is a $x$ factor at the beginning of the first term, resulting  in $\;x\cdot\dfrac12 x^{-\frac12}=\dfrac{x^{\frac12}}2$.

Comment: @Bernard answered it, thank you.

Comment: "Why does $\frac 12x^{−1/2}$ not equal $\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}$"  Um... it does.

Comment: "I see the chain rule is being applied to x−−√ in the denominator,"  No it's not.  It's be applied to $\arctan \sqrt{x}$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the $x$ term multiplying the troublesome expression (from the product rule). So you have
$$
x\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}^2}\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}^2}
$$